# How can I obtain a minimal data frame of only the variables used in a statistical model in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, detection, lm, model.matrix

Take the following example:

```r
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ log(Sepal.Width), data = iris)
```

I would like a copy of `iris` that *only* includes the variables that were involved in making `fit`. I think `model.matrix()` or `model.frame()` don't quite do it because of the `log`; they will include `log(Sepal.Width)` but not `Sepal.Width`. I want basically a minimal version of `iris` that only includes variables that were used in making `fit`. How can I do that? This of course is an example and I would like a more general solution (say you had a number of variables used in making a fit, many passed through transformations that are not necessarily invertible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is `get_all_vars()`

```
get_all_vars(fit, data = iris)
```

Output:

```
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#1            5.1         3.5
#2            4.9         3.0
#3            4.7         3.2
#4            4.6         3.1
#5            5.0         3.6
#6            5.4         3.9
#7            4.6         3.4
# ...
```

This returns untransformed variables (ie, `Sepal.Width` instead of `log(Sepal.Width)`, as seen here:

```
all.equal(iris$Sepal.Width, 
          get_all_vars(fit, data = iris)$Sepal.Width)

#[1] TRUE
```